# Saving NSMutableArray to NSUserDefaults

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsuserdefaults

I have an `NSMutableArray` inside of my `AppDelegate`, and I'm attempting to save it to `NSUserDefaults`. The `NSMutableArray` (strainsfinal) contains a list of favorited items. I want this list to save, and be present even if the app is shut down, and then restarted. Does anyone know why my code isn't working (not saving my data)? See below:

**AppDelegate.m**

```
-(void)updateStrains:(NSDictionary *)item
{        
    NSUserDefaults *currentDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSData *dataSave = [currentDefaults objectForKey:@"strains"];
    if (strainsfinal != nil)
    {
        NSArray *oldSavedArray = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:dataSave];
        if (oldSavedArray != nil)
            strainsfinal = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:oldSavedArray];
        else
            strainsfinal = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }

}
```

**EDIT: Appdelegate.m** So I've changed my above method to the method below (and I thought it should work), but the app crashes, saying: *"Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArguementException', reason: 'NSConcreteAttributedString initwithString: nil 'value'.*

What am I missing?!

```
-(void)updateStrains:(NSDictionary *)item {

    NSData *dataSave = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:strainsfinal];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:dataSave forKey:@"strains"];
        NSNotificationCenter* nc = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
        [nc postNotificationName:@"arrayupdated" object:self userInfo:nil];
        NSLog(@"updated strains %@",strainsfinal);   
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You must add

```
[currentDefaults synchronize];
```

each time after you save something to userDefaults;

But for such kind of data is better to use .plist files. 
Check [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Conceptual/PropertyLists/index.html) for more info.

EDITED Code:

```
-(void)updateStrains:(NSDictionary *)item {
    NSData *dataSave = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:item[@"strainsfinal"]];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:dataSave forKey:@"strains"];
   // NSNotificationCenter* nc = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
   // [nc postNotificationName:@"arrayupdated" object:self userInfo:nil];
    NSLog(@"updated strains %@",strainsfinal);   
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize]; // this will save you UserDefaults
}
```

Comment: I added [currentDefaults synchronize]; to the end of my method, and it doesn't save. What do you mean by, "each time you save something"? Can you show me what the code would look like? Thank you!

Comment: How odd; so that fixes the crash (the app runs smoothly), however when I close down the app and start it up again, all of the favourites are gone.

Comment: @Britany could you please add NSLog (@"%@", item); in the beginning  of your method.And add what NSLog give you.

Comment: This ended up working! See edited code above. Commented out NSNotificationCenter & NSData lines. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

use following method :

```
NSUserDefaults *userDef = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[userDef setObject:array1 forKey:@"DataArra1"];
[userDef setObject:array2 forKey:@"DataArr2"];
[userDef synchronize];
```

To retrieve the information:

```
NSUserDefaults *userDef = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSArray *arrayText2 = [userDef objectForKey:@"DataArra1"];
NSArray *arrayText1 = [userDef objectForKey:@"DataArr2"];
```

Answer (score -1):

You should archive `NSArray` before saving.

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] 
  setObject:[NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:yourArray] 
     forKey:@"yourArray"];
```

and unarchive when getting from `NSUserDefaults`.

```
NSData *data = [currentDefaults objectForKey:@"yourArray"];
if (data != nil)
{
    NSArray *savedArray = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:data];
}
```

Comment: See my edits above. I archived the array, and the app crashes (see error above as well). What am I missing? Lol

Comment: OP, you showed how to saved NSArray instead of NSMutableArray as the question suggests