# Saving with NSKeyedArchiver to NSUserDefaults isn't working...

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm attempting to save an nsmutablearray (strainsfinal) to NSUserDefaults in AppDelegate, but the app crashes, saying:

*"Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArguementException', reason: 'NSConcreteAttributedString initwithString: nil 'value'.*

What am I missing?! Here's my code:

**Appdelegate.m**

```
-(void)updateStrains:(NSDictionary *)item {

    NSData *dataSave = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:strainsfinal];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:dataSave forKey:@"strains"];
        NSNotificationCenter* nc = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
        [nc postNotificationName:@"arrayupdated" object:self userInfo:nil];
        NSLog(@"updated strains %@",strainsfinal);   
}
```

Comment: Add the exception stack trace.

Comment: What objects are in the NSMutableArray ?

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20236845/saving-nsmutablearray-to-nsuserdefaults

Answer (score 0):

Your array is probably contains nil, that will cause your app to crash. And i cant see any string. I think it is a problem in another part of your code.